# Linux Runtime Memory protection

Tags: linux, injection, memory, protection

I'm searching for a solution to protect process memory at runtime level in Linux (just like [GameGuard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NProtect_GameGuard) in Windows). I googled many times but didn't get any useful information.

Does anyone know any existing projects or research about this subject?

Comment: *"research about this article"* - what article are you referring to? Also, protecting process memory *against what*?

Comment: protect memory from malicious code injection, maybe similar to hook, CreateRemoteThread in Windows!

Comment: Is mprotect() the kind of thing you are looking for?

Comment: @schroeder: Yeah, I also thought about this but I didn't define a clear strategy with this. Because once we can use mprotect() to protect the memory, then hacker can also use this to unprotect the memory! So I think it's not effective. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I read of one... You find a very remote place, preferably not on a map anywhere. You put the Linux run time you want to protect in a vault like bunker with no physical access, running on its on dedicate power supply (of course this has to be a perpetual motion machine based power supply), in a facility that has no staff, no network connections and is absolutely guaranteed to be inaccessible. Of course you must remove any USB, or other ingress ports into the machine, and pour super glue into all seams in the boxing of the machine to ensure no one can crack the case and put jumper cables into any communications layer.

One way to protect run time memory... Of course a very restricted and severe way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my solution will be installed in the normal end-user computer. So your ideas maybe not suit in this context!

Comment: I find the audience on this forum, and some of the people who moderate tend to lack a sense of humor, nor believe Socratic method of solving problems. I assumed you were looking for something different, but as some of the other commentators indicated, it was unclear what you were looking for. Personally, it is my opinion that we are chasing a dragon's tail by continuously trying to find a "better way to protect run-time memory". Remember the old physical security theorem - there isn't a lock you can't figure out how to pick. I think we have to look at the problem differently.

Comment: As I described on my post, I wanted to develop a software like a Game Guard (which protect memory of all running processes). All I want here is some good resources to reference but I'venot found any! Thanks for your comments, I think I should describe my problem more clearly.